# change all fonts in powerpoint without opening the file

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I wanted change the all fonts in about 100 powerpoint files, without opening the files. There are several shape types in each slide and each might have a different font. I used `python-pptx` package and wrote the following code to change the fonts of all texts in a powerpoint presentation. Although it does not give any error, it does not work, and the fonts in the file are still whatever they were, for example `Arial`. I also added `print(shape.text)` to make sure that it has found all texts, and it seems that there is no issue there. Is it a bug? Or am I missing anything?

```
prs = Presentation('f10.pptx')

for i, slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        print (shape.has_text_frame)
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            print(shape.text)
            for p in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                for r in p.runs:
                    print(r.font.name)
                    r.font.name = 'Tahoma'
                    print(r.font.name)
                    
prs.save('f10_tahoma.pptx')
```

Besides, it seems that the package does not work for utf-8 characters. I added a text-box on the last slide by adding:

```
text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.clear()  # not necessary for newly-created shape

p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = 'سلام '

font = run.font
font.name = 'Andalus'
font.size = Pt(18)
```

before saving the file to add a textbox with utf-8 characters. It adds it there, and when I check the font it shows that it is set to `Andalus`, but actually it is not  `Andalus`.

Answer (score 2):

With [Aspose.Slides for Python via .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you can easily change all fonts for all texts in your presentations. The following code example shows you how to do this:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

with slides.Presentation('example.pptx') as presentation:
    for slide in presentation.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if isinstance(shape, slides.AutoShape):
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for portion in paragraph.portions:
                        portion.portion_format.latin_font = slides.FontData('Tahoma')
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing.

[Aspose Slides Online Viewer](https://products.aspose.app/slides/viewer) can be used to view presentations without PowerPoint installed.

I work at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

What language is the text of the file? `Run.font` properties work fine for UTF-8, but there is a separate font for cursive scripts like Arabic. Access to that secondary font is not implemented in `python-pptx` unfortunately, but that could explain at least part of the behavior you're seeing.

For roman character text (like that we're using here), there are a couple things to check.

1. The font in question needs to be installed on the machine PowerPoint is running on when the document is opened. Otherwise PowerPoint will substitute a font.
2. The font (typeface) name used in the XML will not always exactly match what appears in the PowerPoint drop-down selection box. You need to give that name to `python-pptx` in the exact form it should appear in the XML. You may need to make an example file that works by hand, perhaps containing a single slide with a single textbox for simplicity, and then inspect the XML of that file to find the "spelling" used for that typeface by PowerPoint.

   You could do that with code like this:

   ```
   prs = Presentation("example.pptx")
   shape = prs.slides[0].shapes[0]
   print(shape._element.xml)
   ```

You should be able to locate the typeface name somewhere in an element like `<p:rPr>` or `<p:defRPr>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The font is for arabic/farsi language. I checked the font as you mentioned, and it looks OK.

Comment: I saved the file as xml, replaced all fonts, and then saved it back as pptx, and it worked! Can I save the file as .xml by using `python-pptx`?